# Windows/Apache/Perl/CGI "access is denied" when reading a file

Tags: windows-server-2008, perl, cgi, apache-2.2

I haven't done anything on a windows machine since I started doing serious sys-admin and development work (all *nix). So I may be asking something easy - but I haven't found the answer by searching.

I've got Windows Server 2008 running Apache 2.2. I can run the "printenv.pl" perl script that came in the cgi-bin dir along with the Apache install just fine...

However, with a script that does the following:

```
#!c:\perl\bin\perl.exe
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
print `type C:\\Some\\Dir\\file.txt`;
```

My apache log just says:

```
[Tue Jun 22 13:13:55 2010] [error] [client 68.230.22.34] Access is denied.\r
```

I can run the same perl script from the dos prompt - so I know it works for my user. I can see in Task Manager that httpd.exe is running with user SYSTEM, so I made sure file.txt was readable to SYSTEM. I even made it readable to Everyone at one point - but I still get the "access is denied" error.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - it turned out that the `C:\some\dir\file.txt` file was encrypted. It took me a while, but I finally started to wonder: "why is that folder in green text" in windows explorer. I have no idea why, but I copied a zip file over, and when they extracted they were encrypted. As soon as I turned that off, the perl script could read.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the user 'SYSTEM' can execute perl.exe?

Comment: Yes, based on the fact that I can run that 'printenv.pl' script through Apache... I checked the properties on the exe as well to be sure...

Comment: Are you certain that Apache isn't jailed to the directory?  Where exactly is the file.txt?  Try moving a copy into the Apache directory it is serving from to make sure.

Comment: That's a good call - I will try asap. What would "jailed" mean on a windows machine? (what controls that, and where is it configured)

Comment: I'm afraid you've hit my Windows knowledge wall.  I can't answer that and google isn't turning anything up.

Comment: Thanks - well you've pointed me in the right direction ... I've confirmed I can 'type' out a file within cgi-bin ... and even when I add the *other* path as an apache 'Alias' and add a corresponding '<directory>' section to allow browsing - I get a permission denied...